# Different catalog for different users

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, catalog, user-roles

I need to find a solution, where different logged in users can have shown different catalogues, decided by user role.

What I need is a basic catalog, that is then extended with the category COMPANY-A and corresponding products, when logged in as user with user role COMPANY-A. I need to be able to do this for multiple different companys.

I prefer a solution where it is as easy as possible for the client to create new products and categories for a specific user role.

Does anyone have a suggestion or know a great extension for this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth you checking out Vinai Kopp's Groups Catalog 2 Module.

https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

It gives you the ability to restrict products by groups. So you would have your base selection of products visible to all groups, then hide specific products from the groups that should not be allowed to see it.

It would lack the ability to extend however in that you cant setup group company A and group company B, which is based on Group Company A. It would restrict at product level based on the current user's group.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Have you tried this plugin in magento 2.0? Since install key is left blank in github, I have uploaded it manually to ftp. But I dont have the Netzarbeiter Extensions menu in stores -> configuration..

Comment: Hi, no I've not, to my knowledge it is only compatible with Magento 1.x as Magento 2.0 is a major rewrite of the entire platform.

Comment: Great. In your opinion, should I even worry about 2.0 yet? Or should that wait until some point in the next year or so?

Comment: It depends on what your doing. Magento have stopped issuing Enterprise licenses for Version 1 so any new enterprise customers must go onto Magento 2 so as an agency developer I'm worrying about it and learning it. If you are doing this for your own website, and wont need to support any other sites you can probably wait a bit - but it is a big learning curve as it has changed significantly.